# Display the contents of an HTML file on my desktop

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, widgets, webkit

I found a very old post on [Display the HTML content on desktop](https://www.kryogenix.org/days/2014/03/03/writing-a-simple-desktop-widget-for-ubuntu/) as a widget. This is an updated answer with the help of these two answers [Answer-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205300/how-can-i-make-my-own-custom-desktop-widgets) and [Answer-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258829/create-a-gtk-window-insensitive-to-show-desktop-and-wont-show-in-launcher).
I tried to run this as a python script "**python file.py**" (correct me if I am wrong bcz I have no background knowledge, just got fascinated with the post and trying to get the working script)

So After running the script I got some errors which I resolved by DuckDuckGoing but still there are some errors that needed some experts.

## Current script

I just updated first three lines, changed WebKit --> WebKit2.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import WebKit2, Gtk, Gdk, Gio, GLib
import signal, os

class MainWin(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, skip_pager_hint=True, skip_taskbar_hint=True)
        self.set_wmclass("sildesktopwidget","sildesktopwidget")
        self.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DOCK)
        self.set_size_request(600,400)
        self.set_keep_below(True)

        #Set transparency
        screen = self.get_screen()
        rgba = screen.get_rgba_visual()
        self.set_visual(rgba)
        self.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,0))

        #Add all the parts
        self.view = WebKit2.WebView()
        self.view.set_transparent(True)
        self.view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,0))
        self.view.props.settings.props.enable_default_context_menu = False
        self.view.load_uri("file:///home/sai/Downloads/todo.html")

        box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(box)
        box.pack_start(self.view, True, True, 0)
        self.set_decorated(False)
        self.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

        #Show all the parts
        self.show_all()
        self.move(100,100)

def refresh_file(*args):
    print args
    mainwin.view.reload()

def file_changed(monitor, file, unknown, event):
    # reload
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, refresh_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gio_file = Gio.File.new_for_path("/home/sai/Downloads/todo.html")
    monitor = gio_file.monitor_file(Gio.FileMonitorFlags.NONE, None)
    monitor.connect("changed", file_changed)

    mainwin = MainWin()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL) # make ^c work
    Gtk.main()
```

## Current Situation

I am getting this error and not able to resolve.

```
#$ python file.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 51, in <module>
    mainwin = MainWin()
  File "file.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.view.set_transparent(True)
AttributeError: 'WebView' object has no attribute 'set_transparent'
```

Please help me to get the working script to display the HTML page as a desktop widget. I am using **Ubuntu Mate 20.04.**

Comment: Just install Windows 98 Plus! Pack. "Active Desktop" HTML widgets are one of the cool new features.

Comment: @hobbs thanks for your suggestion. But I did not understand your idea. :( I mean do this pack change my theme and setting of Ubuntu as well? Or I can use that as an application that display the html page on my ubuntu desktop? please help me to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI - original script runs normally on Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTS (EoL), 16.04 LTS (EoL) and 18.04 LTS.

For Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS you can use the following adapted code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import WebKit2, Gtk, Gdk, Gio, GLib
import signal, os

document="/usr/share/javascript/mathjax/test/sample.html"

class MainWin(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, skip_pager_hint=True, skip_taskbar_hint=True)
        self.set_wmclass("sildesktopwidget","sildesktopwidget")
        self.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DOCK)
        self.set_size_request(600,400)
        self.set_keep_below(True)

        #Set transparency
        screen = self.get_screen()
        rgba = screen.get_rgba_visual()
        self.set_visual(rgba)
        self.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,0))

        #Add all the parts
        self.view = WebKit2.WebView()
        #self.view.set_transparent(True)
        self.view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,0))
        #self.view.props.settings.props.enable_default_context_menu = False
        # configure transparency as in https://github.com/LTSchmiddy/dungeon-commander/blob/8d5c58ca321a05519c8cb1c5afdebba4954cbfca/src/webview/platforms/gtk.py#L132
        configure_transparency(self)
        configure_transparency(self.view)
        wvbg = self.view.get_background_color()
        wvbg.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.set_background_color(wvbg)

        self.view.load_uri("file://"+document)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(box)
        box.pack_start(self.view, True, True, 0)
        self.set_decorated(False)
        self.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

        #Show all the parts
        self.show_all()
        self.move(100,100)

def refresh_file(*args):
    print args
    mainwin.view.reload()

def file_changed(monitor, file, unknown, event):
    # reload
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, refresh_file)

# configure transparency as in https://github.com/LTSchmiddy/dungeon-commander/blob/8d5c58ca321a05519c8cb1c5afdebba4954cbfca/src/webview/platforms/gtk.py#L549
def configure_transparency(c):
    c.set_visual(c.get_screen().get_rgba_visual())
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.ACTIVE, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.BACKDROP, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.DIR_LTR, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.DIR_RTL, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.FOCUSED, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.INCONSISTENT, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.INSENSITIVE, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.PRELIGHT, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    c.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.SELECTED, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0))
    transparentWindowStyleProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    transparentWindowStyleProvider.load_from_data(b"""
        GtkWindow {
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
            background-image:none;
        }""")
    c.get_style_context().add_provider(transparentWindowStyleProvider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gio_file = Gio.File.new_for_path(document)
    monitor = gio_file.monitor_file(Gio.FileMonitorFlags.NONE, None)
    monitor.connect("changed", file_changed)

    mainwin = MainWin()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL) # make ^c work
    Gtk.main()
```

Notes:

1. I'm not Python expert yet, but it works as expected:

   > [image: HTML on Ubuntu MATE desktop]
2. The script needs the packages installed by `sudo apt-get install python2 python-gi gir1.2-webkit2-4.0` .

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed and working fine. :) I really appreciate your effort and time. Thanks again.

Comment: **+1** for fixing that code full of deprecated properties. You gave it a new life  :)

Comment: @N0ebert can you please tell me how to change the position of the desired file? I am not able to sort the position problem. everything else is working.

Comment: Make changes at `self.set_size_request(600,400)` for size and `self.move(100,100)` for position.

Comment: Is there any modern app to display widgets in MATE desktop?

Answer (score 4):

**Life is much easier than that!**

#### Step by step

- Use `google-chrome` in `--app` mode with [`wmctrl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/) like so:

  ```
  google-chrome --app="https://askubuntu.com/" && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,below
  ```

  There you have it... your "widget" is at your desktop... move it, resize it or close it.
- To make it transparent, use [`xprop`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xprop.1.html) like so:

  ```
  xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY "0xCCFFFFFF"
  ```

  Then, **touch it**.
- To strip it naked, use `xprop` *again* like so:

  ```
  xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0"
  ```

  Then, **touch it** *again*.

#### All at once

- You can do all the above in one step, like so:

  ```
  google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --app="https://askubuntu.com/" && \
  wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,550,800 -b add,below && \
  xprop -id "$(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk '{print $5}')" \
  -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY "0xCCFFFFFF" && \
  xprop -id "$(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk '{print $5}')" \
  -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0"
  ```
- `-e 0,0,0,550,800` sets window position and size... the last four numbers. See `man wmctrl`
- `-set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY "0xCCFFFFFF"` sets the window transparency. Change `CC` to one of [these](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4#all-hex-value-from-100-to-0-alpha) to change transparency level.

Comment: Wow, that is really awesome... very short ;). Let me check and if I need more will ask. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate.

Comment: howto use your code on firefox browser? Actually I don't use chrome :(
but your code is working in brave-browser.

Comment: @sai Brave browser is based on Chromium the open source copy of Google Chrome... So yes, that is expected... FireFox has yet to follow in this field.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the information:) will use Brave.

Comment: Thanks, @Raffa, I appreciate all your efforts, but I am getting error in "All at once" I pasted the content in a bash script then I got the widget windows but transparent thing is not working. This is the error:                                                                                                               libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[21845:21845:0410/092918.754945:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

Comment: @sai Add these options `--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer` after `google-chrome` and add delay in your script like `sleep 60` before the command, if you intend to run the script automatically at login... increase the delay a bit if needed so the command runs after your desktop is fully loaded.... and do not install the browser from snap... install the `.deb` package using APT.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Raffa. You are awesome :).
Yeah sure. I actually don't like snap but few of my favorite applications are available only at snap.