# Use App as a desktop background

Tags: youtube, desktop-background

I want to set an app, for example a web browser as a desktop background. So it have dynamic background. For example:
I open youtube,
set the browser as background
dynamic background.
Is there any tools to achieve this? if not what command would be usefull to build this feature?

Comment: What DE are you using? In KDE Plasma you can make a window borderless and set it behind other windows; that appears to be equivalent to what you want (though desktop icons would not be on top of the video).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the contents of an HTML file on my desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329309/display-the-contents-of-an-html-file-on-my-desktop)